# Getting the name of a column in a static browser

Tags: progress-4gl

I need to disable 2 buttons whenever the user clicks on an editable cell of a static browser. This needs to happen in 4 columns (there are other non-editable columns). For this I need to get the column name. I tried placing the code in the browser's ROW-ENTRY trigger, and this works well, EXCEPT for the FIRST time I click into an editable cell, when I get a 10068 error (Load attribute in a chained-attribute expression (a:b:c) must be type handle or a user-defined type and valid 9not UNKNOWN). I have tried using a handle instead of the browsers name, but didn't make any difference. After the first time, the code works and I can get the columns' name without any errors.

The code inside the ROW-ENTRY trigger is as per below:

```
IF br-people:CURRENT-COLUMN:LABEL = "Name"    OR
   br-people:CURRENT-COLUMN:LABEL = "Surname" OR
   br-people:CURRENT-COLUMN:LABEL = "Age"     OR
   br-people:CURRENT-COLUMN:LABEL = "Gender" THEN DO:
       
        bUp:SENSITIVE = FALSE.
        bDown:SENSITIVE = FALSE.
END.
```

I'm using OpenEdge 11.4. Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the ENTRY event of the Browse cell:

```
ON ENTRY OF <table>.<field1> BROWSE <browse-name> 
OR ENTRY OF <table>.<field2> BROWSE <browse-name> 
OR ENTRY OF <table>.<field3> BROWSE <browse-name> 
OR ENTRY OF <table>.<field4> BROWSE <browse-name> 
DO:

END.
```

Depending on your requirements (you mention "click"), you could also use the MOUSE-SELECT-CLICK event. That will fire whenever the use clicks in the cell - regardless if the field already has focus or not.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your quick response.  Using the ENTRY event of the Browse cell worked well. Problem solved! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have it installed to test, but try testing VALID-HANDLE(br-people:CURRENT-COLUMN) before the other conditions. If I'm not mistaken, this fires multiple times and it's possible in one of them it's not filled.

Comment: Thanks Bupereira for your prompt answer. When I used the handle, I tried that and the first time I clicked ,the handle seemed to be invalid. After that it was ok. Not sure why.